# Plotting hyperbolas so that they cross at a certain point

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

I'd like to plot multiple hyperbolas, around the same focus, with the same semi-major axis, but different eccentricities so that they cross at a certain point. 
Given the two eccentricities, e1, e2, how should theta be changed so that they hyperbolas cross at certain r?

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=-1.0      #semi-major axis
n_e1=2.0    #eccentricity of first orbit
n_e2=3.0    #eccentricity of second orbit

theta=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/100)


r1 = a*(1-n_e1**2)/(1+n_e1*np.cos(theta))
r2 = a*(1-n_e2**2)/(1+n_e2*np.cos(theta))


ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(theta, r1, color='r', linewidth=3)
ax.plot(theta, r2, color='b', linewidth=3)
ax.set_rmax(30.0)
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

This gives me two hyperbolas which don't cross.
How should I modify my code so that the hyperbolae cross at a certain r, say r=10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple math: you just solve for `theta` to compute the specific `theta` at which a predefined `r` is reached. Then you add these `offsets` to rotate the second hyperbola.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/400)

a= 1.0      #semi-major axis
r = 10.
e1 = 2.
e2 = 3. 

def get_r(theta, e, a):
    return a*(e**2 - 1)/(1+e*np.cos(theta))

def get_theta(r, e, a):
    return np.arccos((a*(e**2 - 1) -r)/(e*r))

offset1 = get_theta(r, e1, a)
offset2 = get_theta(r, e2, a)

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(theta, get_r(theta, e1, a), color='r', linewidth=2)
ax.plot(theta, get_r(theta - offset2 + offset1, e2, a), color='b', linewidth=2)
ax.set_rmax(30.0)
ax.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry I see my question was ambiguous. Given 2 hyperbolas, with same semimajor axis and eccentricities e1, e2. How should I adjust theta/rotate the plot so that they cross at a certain r.

Comment: Have you tried my code? If it doesn't do what you want, then I still dont understand what you need

Comment: Yes I tried your code. Given a certain r, it finds the eccentricities of 2 hyperbolas which cross at that position. But i want to give the eccentricities, and rotate one of the hyperbolas so that it crosses the other. I don't want to change the shape of the hyperbolas, just their orientation.

Comment: May I ask in what context you need this?? I'm getting worried that I'm just solving your homework for you

Comment: Of course - i'm doing a masters project, here's some of the description: "Cosmic rays striking the surface of Mercury liberate neutrons, some of which escape into orbit. NASA's MESSENGER mission carries a neutron spectrometer and, being in a highly elliptical orbit measures the abundance of neutrons as a function of distance from the surface. This abundance depends upon the rate at which free neutrons decay. The aim of this project is to consider how well MESSENGER data can constrain the neutron lifetime." This hyperbola thing is to help me gain intuition regarding the orbits of neutrons